# Remove all characters except alphabets and numbers from a Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string input field in a form. I get that value in params hash. How should I remove all characters except alphabets and numbers from that string.

Comment: To help you in your journey: http://www.rubular.com/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just to remind people of good 'ol [`tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
asdf.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')
```

which is finding the complement of the character ranges and translating the characters to ''.

I was curious whether using a `\W` character class was faster than ranges and `gsub` vs. `tr`:

```
require 'benchmark'

asdf = [('A'..'z').to_a, ('0'..'9').to_a].join

puts asdf
puts asdf.tr(   '^A-Za-z0-9',    '' )
puts asdf.gsub( /[\W_]+/,        '' )
puts asdf.gsub( /\W+/,           '' )
puts asdf.gsub( /\W/,            '' )
puts asdf.gsub( /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/, '' )
puts asdf.scan(/[a-z\d]/i).join

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("tr:")    { n.times do; asdf.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '');      end }
  x.report("gsub1:") { n.times do; asdf.gsub(/[\W_]+/, '');        end }
  x.report("gsub2:") { n.times do; asdf.gsub(/\W+/, '');           end }
  x.report("gsub3:") { n.times do; asdf.gsub(/\W/, '');            end }
  x.report("gsub4:") { n.times do; asdf.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/, ''); end }
  x.report("scan:")  { n.times do; asdf.scan(/[a-z\d]/i).join;     end }
end

>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
>>              user     system      total        real
>> tr:      0.560000   0.000000   0.560000 (  0.557883)
>> gsub1:   0.510000   0.000000   0.510000 (  0.513244)
>> gsub2:   0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.823816)
>> gsub3:   0.960000   0.000000   0.960000 (  0.955848)
>> gsub4:   0.900000   0.000000   0.900000 (  0.902166)
>> scan:    5.630000   0.010000   5.640000 (  5.630990)
```

You can see a couple of the patterns aren't catching the '_', which is part of `\w`, and, as a result not meeting the OP's request.

Comment: did you tried **asdf.gsub( /[\W_]/, '' )** without the '+'? Does it differ?

Comment: I didn't, but you can. Copy the code to your own system and try it.

Answer (score 22):

Without a regular expression:

```
garbage = 'ab_c<>?AB C!@#123'
puts garbage.delete("^a-zA-Z0-9") #=> abcABC123
```

In which the '^' negates everything after it.

Answer (score 7):

```
=> '^/how/now#(Brown) Cow'.gsub /\W/, '' # or /[\W_]/
=> "hownowBrownCow"
```

...updated based on the comments...

Comment: Or you can just use `.gsub /\W/, ''`, since \W matches any non-word character (while \w matches word charaters).

Comment: "Or you can just use .gsub /\W/, '', since \W matches any non-word character (while \w matches word charaters)". Close, but not quite. `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. `('Z'..'a').to_a.join.gsub(/\W+/, '') #=> "Z_a"`

Comment: I guess the moral is "check the edit history on this answer" and test. :-)

Comment: @the Tin Man: Most Ruby regex howtos define "word character" like this "\w word character [0-9A-Za-z_]".

Comment: It's the same thing. The order of the ranges isn't important, it's the inclusion of the ranges that is; In other words, it doesn't matter whether 'a-z' is before 'A-Z' or '0-9'. All that matters is that they are in there somewhere.

Comment: I know the order doesn't matter, but I didn't really understand what you tried to say in your first comment, so I thought it's about the underscore being included.

Comment: The OP requested removing everything except alphabet and numbers. `\W` would allow '_' to remain. `[\W_]` would capture `'_'` and force it to be removed also, resulting in only alphabetical and numeric characters. You can see that in the benchmark output I created.